# What is the equivalent of the Oracle "Dual" table in MS SqlServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, dual-table

What is the equivalent of the Oracle "Dual" table in MS SqlServer?

This is my `Select`:

```
SELECT pCliente,
       'xxx.x.xxx.xx' AS Servidor,
       xxxx AS Extension,
       xxxx AS Grupo,
       xxxx AS Puerto
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

In `sql-server`, there is no `dual` you can simply do

```
SELECT pCliente,
       'xxx.x.xxx.xx' AS Servidor,
        xxxx AS Extension,
        xxxx AS Grupo,
        xxxx AS Puerto
```

However, if your problem is because you transfered some code from `Oracle` which reference to `dual` you can re-create the table :

```
CREATE TABLE DUAL
(
DUMMY VARCHAR(1)
)
GO
INSERT INTO DUAL (DUMMY)
VALUES ('X')
GO
```

Comment: It would be best to change the queries, instead of introducing a `dual` table in SQL Server. Oracle's optimizer recognizes the dual table as special and skips accessing it, https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1562813956388#19020485993865

Comment: Thank you, this also works in Virtuoso Open-Source DB.

Comment: `dual` was originally created for some internal use case where joining to it would duplicate rows, but at some point things got out of hand and it became common to select from it because Oracle stupidly requires a `FROM` clause even if the value being selected doesn't require a table.

Comment: How about when I want to use [JOIN clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) like at this example `SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 'COL1' COL1, 'COL2' COL2, M FROM DUAL
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT 'COL3-ROW1' M FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 'COL3-ROW2' M FROM DUAL) ON 1=1
)`

Comment: I had a simil issue. I had to write a particular query in a framework that write query by itself. I used the table `(values('x')) DUAL(DUMMY)` to retrieve the result from a query that has a single column with an `ANY` result (in bold what writes the framework, in italic what I put as parameter): **SELECT** _CASE WHEN 'X' = ANY (SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END RESULT_ **FROM** _(VALUES('X')) DUAL(DUMMY)_ . It works well in most SQL engines.

Answer (score 37):

You don't need *DUAL* in MSSQLserver

**in oracle**

```
select 'sample' from dual
```

**is equal to**

```
SELECT 'sample'
```

**in sql server**

Comment: I see no reason to answer the same one year later after accepted answer...

Comment: Same answer but clearer.  In saying that, I ran both examples without a FROM and got an error.

Answer (score 6):

While you usually don't need a `DUAL` table in SQL Server as explained by [Jean-François Savard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28371433/521799), I have needed to emulate `DUAL` for syntactic reasons in the past. Here are three options:

#### Create a `DUAL` table or view

```
-- A table
SELECT 'X' AS DUMMY INTO DUAL;

-- A view
CREATE VIEW DUAL AS SELECT 'X' AS DUMMY;
```

Once created, you can use it just as in Oracle.

#### Use a common table expression or a derived table

If you just need `DUAL` for the scope of a single query, this might do as well:

```
-- Common table expression
WITH DUAL(DUMMY) AS (SELECT 'X')
SELECT * FROM DUAL

-- Derived table
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 'X'
) DUAL(DUMMY)
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server there is no dual table. If you want to put a `WHERE` clause, you can simple put it directly like this:

`SELECT 123 WHERE 1<2`

I think in MySQL and Oracle they need a FROM clause to use a WHERE clause.

`SELECT 123 FROM DUAL WHERE 1<2`

Comment: Not sure why people didn't like Heng's answer - Heng expanded the previous answers in that Heng pointed out that you can use a where clause without the from as well, which the other solutions didn't mention.

Answer (score 1):

This could be of some help I guess, when you need to join some tables based on local variables and get the information from those tables:

Note: Local variables must have been

```
Select  @XCode     as 'XCode '
       ,@XID       as 'XID   '  
       ,x.XName    as 'XName '
       ,@YCode     as 'YCode '
       ,@YID       as 'YID   '
       ,y.YName    as 'YName '
From (Select 1 as tst) t
Inner join Xtab x on x.XID = @XID
Inner join Ytab y on y.YID = @YID
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler than that.
Use literal values to establish data types.
Put quotes around column names if they need special characters.
Skip the WHERE clause if you need 1 row of data:

```sql
SELECT  'XCode' AS XCode
       ,1 AS XID  
       ,'XName' AS "X Name"
       ,'YCode' AS YCode
       ,getDate() AS YID
       ,'YName' AS "Your Name"
 WHERE 1 = 0
```