# SQL getting averages with multiple joins

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I'm trying to write a single query using 3 tables.
The tables and their columns that I will be using are:

```
Sec – ID, Symbol
Hss – Code, HDate, Holiday
Fddd – ID, Date, Price
```

Given a symbol `AAA`, I need to get the **ID** from the first table and match it with the ID from the third table.  The second table's date must match the third table's dates with the condition of `Code=1` and `Holiday=1`.

The Dates in the second and third table are in ascending order with most recent dates at the bottom.  I want to get the average `50 day` and `200 day` prices.  The dates in the tables are in ascending order so I want to make it descending and select the `top 50` and `200` to get the average prices.

So far I can only get one average.  I cannot add a second `SELECT TOP 50` or add a `subquery` within the second `avg()`.

```
SELECT AVG(TwoHun)TwoHunAvg   --, AVG(Fifty) AS FiftyAvg 
FROM (SELECT TOP 200 Fddd.price AS TwoHun    --, TOP 50 Fddd.price AS Fifty
FROM Sec 
JOIN Fddd
ON Sec.ID = Fddd.ID AND Sec.symbol = 'AAA' 
JOIN Hss 
ON Fddd.date = Hss.Hdate AND Hss.Code = 1 AND Hss.Holiday = 1 
ORDER BY Fddd.Date DESC) AS tmp;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to mention the database you're using.

Comment: It would also help to have sample data in order to be able to test! Also your question is a bit confusing, please provide 2 tables. One with data, and one with what you want as the results.

Comment: @mustaccio I think it's ms access or SQL server. Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your using SQL Server or MS Access.

One quick solution would be to have your total query as a subquery and then copy a modified version as a second subquery.

Quick rough example:

```
    SELECT (SELECT
         AVG(Fifty) AS FiftyAvg
       FROM (SELECT TOP 50
         Fddd.price AS Fifty
       FROM Sec
       JOIN Fddd
         ON Sec.ID = Fddd.ID
         AND Sec.symbol = 'AAA'
       JOIN Hss
         ON Fddd.date = Hss.Hdate
         AND Hss.Code = 1
         AND Hss.Holiday = 1
       ORDER BY Fddd.Date DESC) AS tmp)
       AS FiftyAvg,
       (SELECT
         AVG(TwoHun) TwoHunAvg
       FROM (SELECT TOP 200
         Fddd.price AS TwoHun
       FROM Sec
       JOIN Fddd
         ON Sec.ID = Fddd.ID
         AND Sec.symbol = 'AAA'
       JOIN Hss
         ON Fddd.date = Hss.Hdate
         AND Hss.Code = 1
         AND Hss.Holiday = 1
       ORDER BY Fddd.Date DESC) AS tmp)
       AS TwoHundredAverge;
```

Comment: Am I correct that this query assumes `Dual` is a saved table in database of one record?

Comment: actually dual is a dummy table keyword. The actual queries are the subqueries

Comment: Actually no dual table reference is needed, reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28371433/1688441

Answer (score 0):

Consider a union query which even scales for other Averages. I add a Type column to indicate the Averages.

```
SELECT '200 DAY AVG' As Type, AVG(TwoHun) As Avg
FROM 
  (SELECT TOP 200 Fddd.price AS TwoHun
   FROM Sec 
   INNER JOIN Fddd ON Sec.ID = Fddd.ID 
   INNER JOIN Hss ON Fddd.date = Hss.Hdate
   WHERE Sec.symbol = 'AAA' AND Hss.Code = 1 AND Hss.Holiday = 1 
   ORDER BY Fddd.Date DESC) AS tmp;

UNION

SELECT '50 DAY AVG' As Type, AVG(FiftyHun) As Avg
FROM 
  (SELECT TOP 50 Fddd.price AS FiftyHun
   FROM Sec 
   INNER JOIN Fddd ON Sec.ID = Fddd.ID
   INNER JOIN Hss ON Fddd.date = Hss.Hdate
   WHERE Sec.symbol = 'AAA' AND Hss.Code = 1 AND Hss.Holiday = 1 
   ORDER BY Fddd.Date DESC) AS tmp;
```

Also, I moved some of your join expressions to where clause which should not change performance but does in readability.

Comment: This isn't exactly what the user asked for since you are providing the values in two different rows when instead they were requested as two different columns.

Comment: Correct, hence the "consider". You beat me to the original request. I provide an alternative to OP and maybe future readers. And 100-day, 30-day, 15-day can be added for an Avgs dataset. Plus, there's the performance aspect of quadruple vs double subqueries...